# How to skip an index in a for loop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to skip in a random condition that if true, will skip a loop, but results are printing all elements `0,1,2,3,4`
I know in Java if index is incremented index will skip, but this is not happening Swift.?

Update: this is a simplified version of some program I wrote, the `print()` has to be happen right after each loop, and index is ONLY incremented in some unknown conditions, I want it to behave like JAVA.

```
for var index in 0..<5 {
  print(index)//this prints 0,1,2,3,4, this must happen right after for loop
  if some unknown condition {
      index+=1
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use 'continue' with if clause like if index == 2 then continue!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, because you want to check if an unknown condition is true... What do you want? A random number generator which will return which index should be removed?? Please be more clear.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My "unknown" condition is found inside the for-loop to determine whether the next iteration is skipped or not. I turned out declare a new variable to do the job

Comment: the second method I used is by while-loop, instead of for-loop. In that way the index is incremented as you want

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The index is automatically incremented in the loop, you can skip an index with a where clause:

```
for index in 0..<5 where index != 2 {
    print(index)
}
```

Comment: @vandian : best answer among all :) Hence up vote :)

Comment: what if $0 != 2 is not a known condition?

Comment: @miracle-doh simply replace `index != 2` with the condition you'd like to test (eg. `for index in 0..<5 where myCondition(index) { ... }`)

Comment: what if you're looping through objects that dont have a compareable interface

I just need to skip the first index of my list. In something like java I could just start the loop at 
`for(int i = 1 ...` instead of `i = 0`

Answer (score 36):

Please try this one:

```
for var index in 0..<5 {

  if index == 2 {
     continue
  }
  print(index)//this prints 0,1,3,4
}
```

Comment: maybe without "2"(in the comment)

Comment: @ItsMeDom ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This works. Not sure if it is the best way to do this.

```
var skip = false
for var index in 0..<5 {
  if (skip) {
    skip = false
    continue
  }

  print(index)
  if index == 2 {
      skip = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop:

```
for var index in 0..<5 {
if index != 2{
   print(index)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for var index in 0..<5 {

  if index == 2 {
      //dont do anything
  }
  else {
     print(index)
  }
}
```

Isn't it that simple ??

Comment: well, if your upperlimit is 100million, it would be nice to simply skip to the number

Answer (score 0):

```
(0..<5).filter({$0 != 2}).forEach{ x in print(x)}
```

(or) when the condition is unknown,

```
(0..<5).filter(isNumber2).forEach{ x in print (x)}
```

**Note:** `isNumber2` is an external function that returns the boolean after evaluating the condition on the number. Your implementation of this function could be different.

```
var isNumber2: (Int) -> (Bool) = { return $0 != 2}
```

Comment: what if $0 != 2 is not a known condition?

Answer (score 0):

for index in 0 ..< 5 where (give your condition here) {
    print(index)
}

If the condition is to skip index 3,
for index in 0 ..< 5 where index != 3 {
    print(index)
}

Comment: @miracle-doh i dont think the boolean variable is needed to perform something simple as this